# Finding the basis of the kernel of a polynomial function

Tags: linear-algebra

Recall that P$_2$($\mathbb{R}$) denotes the vector space of degree-2 polynomial functions *p*: $\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Let *T*: P$_2$($\mathbb{R}$) $\rightarrow$ P$_2$($\mathbb{R}$) be the linear map given by *T*(*ax$^2$* + *bx* + *c*) = *ax$^2$*

Write down a basis for ker(*T*).

I'm fine with finding an actual basis. What I don't really understand is how to find the kernel when dealing with polynomial functions ie. I'm would be fine if the map was *T*: $\mathbb{R}^3$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}^4$ defined by *T*(*x*, *y*, *z*) = ...

I know that the ker(T) is all of the vectors where a = 0 (doesn't matter what b and c are) but how to represent that mathematically

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of polynomials is just dressing on the problem, intended to make it a bit more circuitous. You can find the kernel by translating the problem into pure linear algebraic terms – what is $T$, what are the vectors as pure matrices of numbers? – then find the kernel in that stripped-down formulation, and lastly add the dressing back.

Comment: We haven't really done much on matrices but I would guess the vectors would be something like (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 1) though I don't really understand what you mean by translating the problem into "pure linear algebraic terms."

Comment: @LABrudvikLindner "pure linear algebraic" means "without those $x$ and $x^2$ and polynomial stuff, just hard numbers."